# redirect to admin route when admin not loged in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, model-view-controller, laravel-routing

I wanted to check if the user logged in and then accessed the dashboard route; otherwise redirected to the admin login page, But it always turned me to the admin page while I entered my email and password.

**Middleware**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        // validation successful!
        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect('admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['protectPage']],function(){
    Route::view('dashboard','admin_dashboard');
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function admin(Request $req)
{
    $email = $req->input('email');
    $password = $req->input('password');
    $req->session()->put(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]);
    $user = Admin::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
    
    if ($user && $user->password === $password) {
        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        {
            return redirect('admin')->with('failed', 'Invalid Credentials');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect admin page only when user is not logged in.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check())
    {
        return redirect('admin');
    }  

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Its not working. It Still redirect to admin page when I want to log in.

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil, where is your log in route? how you define it?

Comment: Route::get('admin',function(){
    return view('admin');
});

Comment: I have create admin route instead of login

Comment: Do you also have a user model or just admin?

Comment: Just admin model